Why is my React/Javascript event not working?
I am writing an Automation as a Service frontend (open source) with a task display page. I've done all the common debug on it and identified that the problem seems to be with the onChange handler just from process of elimination mostly, but also using debug statements all over the code, and it's not even getting in the handler event function. So, it's not that the web component is blocked or anything (except by other events most probably).
The error was introduced because I added to the process on this page. Originally, this page had a button that requested a file upload. The table on the page takes a JSON or YAML file and lists the tasks that will happen in that file into a table so they can be seen and edited. That all worked fine. The rows were displayed in the table.
Then, I had the brilliant idea of installing dJango_eventstream & daphne to enable server-side events so I could display a dialog of what's happening when the file is imported rather than making the user wait patiently for a minute (no user has patience). That broke it, but the break seems to be from adding multiple new events to the page to handle the Import Dialog window and SSE events. The button code and everything else was working before. I rewrote the event handler to combine things in a more concise way, but with no luck.
I freely admit, I'm a python developer here. This is my first react & first javascript project, so expect that I have no idea what I'm doing. I can figure my way around just because it's similar to what I know, but javascript events are vastly over my head on the whole. I may somewhat understand the individual concepts here and then fallen completely flat on trying to combine them.
The offending code (table setup removed to make it small-ish):
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { DataGrid } from '@mui/x-data-grid';
import Box from '@mui/material/Box';
import Button from '@mui/material/Button';
import Typography from '@mui/material/Typography';
import CloudUploadIcon from '@mui/icons-material/CloudUpload';
import Copyright from '../internals/components/Copyright';
import axios from 'axios';
import ImportDialog from './importDialog';

const API_URL = 'http://backend:8000/';


const callRestApi = (endpoint, method = 'GET', body) => {
  const sessionToken = window.sessionStorage.getItem('sessionToken');

  const headers = {
    'Accept': 'application/json',
  };

  if (sessionToken) {
    headers['Authorization'] = `Token ${sessionToken}`;
  } else {
    console.warn('No session token found in storage. This request might fail if authorization is required.');
  }

  return axios({
    method,
    url: `${API_URL}/${endpoint}`,
    data: body,
    headers,
  }).catch(err => {
    console.error('Request failed:', err);
  });
};

export default function Tasks() {
  const [tasks, setTasks] = useState([]);
  const [selectedFile, setSelectedFile] = useState(null);
  const [dialogOpen, setDialogOpen] = useState(false);
  const [importResults, setImportResults] = useState('');

  useEffect(() => {
    callRestApi("tasks/", 'GET', null).then((res) => {
      if (res && res.data) {
        setTasks(res.data);
      } else {
        console.error("Failed to load tasks data.");
      }
    });
  }, []);

  const handleFileChange = (event) => {
    alert("Handle File Change");
    const file = event.target.files[0];
    if (file) {
      setSelectedFile(file);
      handleFileUpload(file);
    }
    event.target.value = ''; // reset the file input
  };

  const handleFileUpload = async (file) => {
    if (!file) {
      alert("Please select a file first.");
      return;
    }

    const formData = new FormData();
    formData.append('file', file);
    try {
      const uploadResponse = await axios.post(`${API_URL}api/tasks/api_upload/`, formData, {
        headers: { 'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data' }
      });
      console.log('File uploaded:', uploadResponse.data);

      // Start SSE after upload
      const eventSource = new EventSource(`${API_URL}/events/import/`);
      const messages = [];

      eventSource.onmessage = (event) => {
        const data = JSON.parse(event.data);
        messages.push(data.text);
        setImportResults(messages.join("\n"));
        setDialogOpen(true);
      };

      eventSource.onerror = (error) => {
        console.error('SSE error:', error);
        eventSource.close();
      };
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('Error uploading file:', error);
    }
  };
  
  const handleDialogClose = () => {
    setDialogOpen(false);
  };

  return (
    <Box sx={{ width: '100%', maxWidth: { sm: '100%', md: '1700px' } }}>
      <Box sx={{ width: '100%', maxWidth: { sm: '100%', md: '1700px' } }}>
        <Typography color="blue" component="h2" variant="h6" sx={{ mb: 2 }}>
          Tasks
        </Typography>
        <input
          type="file"
          onChange={handleFileChange}
          accept=".yaml,.json"
          id="file-input"
          style={{ display: 'none' }}
        />
        <Button
          variant="contained"
          startIcon={<CloudUploadIcon />}
          onClick={() => {
            document.getElementById('file-input').click();
          }}
        >
          Upload API Definition
        </Button>
      </Box>

      <Box sx={{ width: '100%', maxWidth: { sm: '100%', md: '1700px' } }}>
        <DataGrid
          autoHeight
          checkboxSelection
          columns={columns}
          rows={tasks}
          getRowClassName={(params) =>
            params.indexRelativeToCurrentPage % 2 === 0 ? 'even' : 'odd'
          }
          initialState={{
            pagination: { paginationModel: { pageSize: 20 } },
          }}
          pageSizeOptions={[10, 20, 50]}
          density="compact"
        />
        <Copyright sx={{ my: 4 }} />
      </Box>

      {/* Import Dialog */}
      <ImportDialog
        open={dialogOpen}
        handleClose={handleDialogClose}
        importResults={importResults}
      />
    </Box>
  );
}


I tried manually triggering the button, and that only worked when I put the event function directly in the onClick event in the button. It won't work the right way, which also points to the event not firing.

I tried moving the button to another spot to see if the theme was blocking it with no luck.

I tried taking out all the code except just the button def and the event to see where the problem was, but since I left in the event definitions, I think that's why that failed.

then after putting in more debug statements and realizing it only failed when it was calling it through events, I re-wrote the event handler and took out all this (this) references, still with no luck.



I ended up solving this purely by accident, and it was the most ridiculous thing too. There was nothing wrong with the code. I use a Mac for development in docker. After at least 2 to 3 days of fighting this, I happened to notice a similar dialog didn't work in another un-related application. Macs rarely show bugs or problems, and they're meant to not be rebooted, so it never occurred to me that I might've hit a bug that turned off file dialogs on the Mac interface. If I hadn't noticed this by accident, I could have gone a month without resolving this. So, it was an event problem, just not in my application. Some bug in the dialog events had turned off the file dialogs on the mac interface completely and globally. A simple reboot and re-loading the docker images solved it.
Thanks.
